# Samba guest ok is always Yes

Tags: linux, networking, samba

I want to have a samba share set up that allows only a single user "peter" to connect. However, even if I set `guest ok = no`, when running `testparm -s` it says `Yes`. Does this mean that guest access is enabled, and how can I disable it successfully?

I've configured Samba as follows:

**smb.conf:**

```
[global]
        workgroup = SIMERNES
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        log level = 5

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw
        encrypt passwords = true
        smb encrypt = required
        server min protocol = SMB3

[shared]
        comment = Shared Folder
        path = /var/samba/myfolder
        valid users = peter
        guest ok = no
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        write list = samba
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        printable = no
```

**`testparm -s:`**

```
WARNING: The "encrypt passwords" option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
        printcap name = cups
        security = USER
        server min protocol = SMB3
        workgroup = SIMERNES
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        cups options = raw
        smb encrypt = required


[shared]
        comment = Shared Folder
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /var/samba/myfolder
        read only = No
        valid users = peter
        write list = samba
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `public = yes`. This is a synonym for `guest ok`, so it actually overwrites the same setting.